# Is the ProjectServer REST service really that much slower than the ProjectData service?

Tags: rest, performance, project-server

I have a couple REST queries that are pretty much identical, asking for Tasks who's Finish date falls between two specified dates:

```
axios.get(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectData/Projects(guid'" + projID + "')/Tasks?$filter=TaskFinishDate gt datetime'2017-02-01T00:00:00' and TaskFinishDate le datetime'2017-03-01T00:00:00'")
```

and

```
axios.get(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/ProjectServer/projects('" + projID + "')/tasks?$filter=Finish gt datetime'2017-02-01T00:00:00' and Finish le datetime'2017-03-01T00:00:00'")
```

They both work, and return the same 159 tasks.

However, the query to the `ProjectData` service returns in 500-600 *milli*seconds at the **most** (usually only takes 200-300), while the query to the `ProjectServer` service regularly takes 55-60 full seconds.

Is it really that much slower, or should I be talking to my Sys Admin to look for something wrong in the Project Server / PWA configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the information in Ariwaba's answer is quite interesting, in my particular case the *enormous* discrepancy between under 1 second response times for the `ProjectData` endpoint and the nearly one full minute response times for the `ProjectServer` endpoint did ultimately have to do with the configuration of the server.

I don't know exactly what was wrong, but after one of my Sys Admins did some routine patching of the Project server, the `ProjectServer` endpoint sped up to "normal" speeds.  It's still slightly slower than the `ProjectData` endpoint, but I now get results in a second or two, as opposed to 60.

Answer (score 1):

That could happen because, ProjectServer API check access right for each data returned. Unlike ProjectData where it was mean for admin access to get data for reporting.

Here's a note from TechNet forum

> These are two important advantages. Example: _api/ProjectServer/Projects()?$Select=Id,Name will give the user a list of all Project Names he or she has access to.

While projectdata

> With _api/ProjectData, there is no security model applied. If you allow "Global Permissions - General - Access Project Server Reporting Service", user will have access to all information across instance.

another notes at bottom

> _api/ProjectData is just optimized for reporting, therefore the additional global permission.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/243ce8b3-5843-4b3d-9d21-331d6bb102f6/rest-queries-on-projectonline-should-use-apiprojectdata-or-apiprojectserver?forum=projectserver2010general